Why is the change of the Published property not changing the Subview?
I have my ChallengeViewModel as an ObservableObject dafined like this:
class ChallengeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    private let challenge: Challenge
    private var taskStatus: [TaskStatus]
    private var currentTaskIndex: Int?
    public var taskCount: Int {
        taskStatus.count
    }
    @Published public var currentTaskStatus: TaskStatus?
    
    init(_ challenge: Challenge) {
        self.challenge = challenge
        self.taskStatus = [TaskStatus]()
        
        self.taskStatus = generateTasks(challenge)
        if !taskStatus.isEmpty {
            self.currentTaskIndex = 0
            self.currentTaskStatus = self.taskStatus[self.currentTaskIndex!]
        }
        
        print(self.currentTaskStatus)
    }
    
    public func nextTask() -> Bool {
        if var index = self.currentTaskIndex {
            if index < (self.taskStatus.count - 1) {
                index += 1
                self.currentTaskStatus = self.taskStatus[index]
                self.currentTaskIndex = index
                
                return true
            }
        }
        
        return false
        
    }
    
    private func generateTasks(_ challenge: Challenge) -> [TaskStatus] {
        /* Tasks are generated here and returned */
    }
    
    func validateResult(result: Int) {
        if var status = currentTaskStatus, let index = self.currentTaskIndex {
            status.passed = result == status.result
            self.currentTaskStatus = status
            self.taskStatus[index] = status
        }
    }
}

Now there is a view to display a current task a later the summary when all tasks are passed.
struct ChallengeView: View {
    @StateObject var challengeViewModel: ChallengeViewModel
    @State var result: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        if let taskStatus = challengeViewModel.currentTaskStatus {
            CurrentChallengeView(result: $result, taskStatus: taskStatus, validateResult:  {
                if let intRes = Int(result) {
                    challengeViewModel.validateResult(result: intRes)
                }
            }, nextTask: { _ = challengeViewModel.nextTask() })
        } else {
            Text("No task set")
        }
        
    }
}

And finally my CurrentTaskView:
struct CurrentChallengeView: View {
    @Binding var result: String
    @State var taskStatus: TaskStatus
    var validateResult: () -> Void
    var nextTask: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                VStack {
                    TaskView(task: taskStatus.task, width: proxy.size.width * 0.8, result: $result)
                    
                    if taskStatus.passed == nil {
                        Button {
                            //Validate current question
                            validateResult()
                        } label: {
                            Text("Check")
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                .padding()
                                .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.8)
                                .background(.green)
                                .cornerRadius(30)
                        }
                    } else {
                        Button {
                            //Switch to next question
                            nextTask()
                        } label: {
                            Text("Next")
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                .padding()
                                .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.8)
                                .background(taskStatus.passed! ? .green : .red)
                                .cornerRadius(30)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .background {
                Image("background")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
        }
    }
}


No when I press the Check-button the validation action is triggered and works properly. But I cannot see in my debugging session the value of currentTaskStatus because of the @Published modifier.
But anyway the passed property should be different from nil and therefore a different Button should be displayed, but my view is not changing.

Why is taskStatus a @State in CurrentChallengeView? The rule is: If the view owns/creates the instance, use @State otherwise use @Binding if the value is going to be modified. If just a value is passed use a simple instance property. This is the reason why @State properties are supposed to be declared always as private. Same applies to @StateObject.  Why is challengeViewModel not being created in ChallengeView and why is it not private?

ViewModel is not created in ChallengeView because it needs a CoreData entity to create and I can't get set the StateObject-property in the init of the ChallengeView

If the view model is not owned by the view you have to use @ObservedObject. @State… represents the source of truth owned by the current view.

In SwiftUI the View structs are your view model already so try removing the object
